# How to get facebook and twitter like gmail webview for android?

Tags: android, gmail, single-sign-on, android-2.2-froyo

I have got a requirement in my app where I want to provide login via google/gmail account.

I have already done it for facebook and twitter usind there respective sdk's          **(fb-dev app & twitter4j)**
Now I want to achieve the same for gmail, i.e. a webview that loads when a button is clicked and ask for gmail credentials of the user and on successful login provide me with

`access-token / uname / gender etc.` basic details or whatever details provided by google.

> Before you tell me that every android device has a gmail app configured and so gmail login is not required like fb/twitter. In that case I would want to know how do I achieve this.

**API and code snippet would really help. If I can provide the same webview like interface for gmail also then it would be best.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Google+ developers [API](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started). Look at this [project](https://github.com/imellon/Google-Plus-Android-Sample) on github and this [article](http://www.imellon.com/blog/2011/11/24/integrating-google-api-to-android/).

Comment: This does all for me but it doesn't return the email address by which the user has authenticated the app.